# Derivative of ODE with respect to parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

For each value of a parameter $a \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x(a,t)$ be defined by the ODE

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=F(a,x,t)$$

where $F$ is (say) smooth and, for each fixed $a$, Lipschitz in $x$. It is well known in this case that $x$ is well-defined and is smooth with respect to $a$.

**Question (general):** What is known about the derivatives of $x$ with respect to $a$?

If this question is too general to be helpful, here's a more specific one:

**Question (specific)**: If $F(a,x,t)$ is zero unless $x \in [-B,B]$ for some constant $B$, does this imply that all the derivatives of $x$ with respect to $a$ are bounded functions of $t$?

(An answer to either question could be a reference to a book)

The obvious thing to do is to write down an ODE satisfied by 
$y:=\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$, which is, I think,

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}y$$

and this could be used to study the first derivative (and similar for the higher ones). But these equations get a little messy for higher derivatives.